# how can i separate filter by function from header text or v-text-field in Vuetify v-data-table

Tags: vuetify.js, v-data-table, vuetify-datatable

[image]As you can see in this codepen link, I have replaced the header text with `v-text-field` but the problem is the v-text-field is attached with `filterBy` icon (the up-down arrow icon) as well. When i click on the text-field the filterBy function is working that i dont want. So far I think the `@click` event is covering whole area. I wish to separate the text-field and filterBy behavior. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/MicroDreamIT/pen/vYRvMza

Comment: One way to achieve this is by removing a default sorting from the column and add a custom sort icon with the click in the template slot.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the filter option on v-table columns by using the property 'sortable'.
Your headers data should look like that :

```js
headers: [
      {
        text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
        align: "left",
        value: "name",
        sortable: false // this will disable filter property and hide the icon
      },
      { text: "Calories", value: "calories", sortBy: true },
      { text: "Fat (g)", value: "fat" },
      { text: "Carbs (g)", value: "carbs" },
      { text: "Protein (g)", value: "protein" },
      { text: "Iron (%)", value: "iron" }
    ],
```

Comment: I need sortable function as well, but it should not work when i click on text field.